# SSRS: consulta con Parámetro de múltiples valores

Tags: ssrs

que tal?
Tengo un problema con la consulta de un reporte en reporting services. He creado un parámetro de múltiples valores y cuando, en la ejecución, selecciono más de un valor tira el siguiente error: An espression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

La consulta que estoy ejecutando para el dataset es la siguiente:

```
declare @A INT
declare @B INT
declare @C INT
declare @D INT

set @A=0
set @B=0
set @C=0
set @D=0

if @paramOpcion='A'
     set @A=1
if @paramOpcion='B'
     set @B=1
if @paramOpcion='C'
     set @C=1
if @paramOpcion='D'
     set @D=1


exec spAAA @A,@B,@C,@D
```

Podrán darme una mano? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné cambiando la consulta de esta manera:

```
declare @A INT
declare @B INT
declare @C INT
declare @D INT

set @A=0
set @B=0
set @C=0
set @D=0

if 'A' in (@paramOpcion)
     set @A=1
if 'B' in (@paramOpcion)
     set @B=1
if 'C' in (@paramOpcion)
     set @C=1
if 'D' in (@paramOpcion)
     set @D=1

exec spAAA @A,@B,@C,@D
```

Muchas gracias!!!